# Apache Airflow and XlsxWriter Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, xlsxwriter, airflow-2.x

I'm trying to write a DAG. It's a simple python code. My code uses xlsxwriter. it works in my terminal. but when I'm trying to run it via Airflow, it gives me an error saying:

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'"

I'm kinda new to this and don't have any experience. Could anyone help me? can you tell me why airflow doesn't recognize the xlsxwriter module?

P.S. the code just does this:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Yesterday_Orders_Delivery.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Raw_Data')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('order_slots'), 
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Delayed_Delivery')
    workbook.close()
```

I tried thousands of times pip install xlsxwriter in several modifications. I also tried to install xlsxwriter via airflow like this:

```
def install_xlsxwriter():
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", 'xlsxwriter'])
```

but it did not help.

Comment: are using docker to run airflow or you just installed it in your host? if it's in your host, do you use the default environment, or you created a new virtual/conda env?

Comment: developer from our team had installed it and runs on amazon's redshift server.